# Not able to see tab bar controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, master-detail

I am working on Xcode 5 and have embedded a tab bar controller to a Master-Detail application templates MasterViewController. But for some reasons the tab bar is not visible. A tab bar should be visible in all the screens connecting the Navigation Controller but that cannot be seen. I have already coded lot of functionality in my application using Master-Detail view controller and now my application requires the functionality of building a tab bar controller. 
I have looked for ways of resizing the size of table view in the MasterViewController so that tab bar is visible. But I am not sure of how to resize it, as like normal table views this table view does not give markers to resize it. 
I have tried changing the streching setting by of the table view and changing its height. But it does not help.

Please help with your ideas around this. I am extremely thankful for your time.

Regards, 
Sameeksha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the storyboard builder, when selecting the related UIViewController, there are a few parameters used to make the preview, you might by accident turned off some features.

In your storyboard, select one of the view controllers, go to `Attribute Inspector` (Option + Command + 4) and under `Simulated Metrics` set the value of `Bottom Bar` to `Inferred` if it is set to none or any other values.

Comment: Although I could not find the bottom bar option which could be checked to inferred, may be because I am on Xcode 5, but i unchecked the option Under Bottom Bar under the Simulated Metrics in attribute inspector and now I am able to see the tab bar. Many Many thanks.

Comment: I was referring to xCode 5, I'm glad your problem's gone. Cheers